# como crear switches con array y/o for en android studio

Tags: android-studio

lo que pasa es que necesito hacer esta vista en android studio en la parte de java, pragmáticamente pero hasta ahora no eh encontrado la manera obviamente centrada en la pantalla ya que se agregaran posterior mente mas botones y tengo entendido que se puese hacer con un ciclo for me comentaron tambien que con un arreglo espero me puedan ayudar gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí],

Comment: para centrarlo, usa `constraintLayout` y configúralo para hacerlo responsivo. anexo [esta documentación en inglés](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: Deberías editar tu pregunta y añadir el código con el que has estado trabajando y, a partir de ahí, exponer de manera concreta tu problema o duda teniendo el código como referencia.

Comment: ok ahorita la edito, de hecho no tengo codigo esto lo hice agregando cada switch de manera manual arrastrando cada uno pero necestio hacerlo con algun arreglo en java

Comment: Puedes intentar algo usando un listview personalizado donde le añades el botón switch y el textview.

Comment: muchas gracias voy a intentarlo, lo que pasa esque necestio solo crear los switch con for

Comment: Pegale un vistazo a esta pregunta, seguro que te sera util.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500710/android-add-components-dynamically-to-layout

Comment: muchas gracias!! voy a revisarlo!!